# How to get attributes values separately for each container present on the webpage in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is in continuation to [How to get attributes of container in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768580/how-to-get-attributes-of-container-in-jquery), I have different containers on my webpage and all of them have `<div id = "some values">`. Now how can I get attributes values separately for each component?

Is there any way I can know which attribute id belong to which container div?

Currently I am using:

```
var id = $( '.promotion' ).attr( 'id' );
```

But if I have multiple promotional components on page and all have same div attribute as id than how can I relate that this particular attribute id belonged to this specific container?

**Update**: I am having a function which is called for each container present on the page and so if I am using above mentioned code than will it not always return me the first match for id in the div and would never go to other divs and so I will always get same value for id which is for the first container ? If so than what is the work around for this ?

```
var id = $( '.promotion' ).this.attr( 'id' );

var id = $( '.promotion' ).$this.attr( 'id' );

var id = this.$( '.promotion' ).attr( 'id' );
```

How would I know if the attribute value is for current container, so how should I use this properly to get this information ?

Hope this question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through and process each div individually

```
$(".promotion").each(function() {
    var id = this.id; // 'this' is the html element, not the jquery object
});
```

**Update**

```
function myfunc() {
   alert(this);
}

// inside myfunc, this will be the window
myfunc(); 
// call (also: apply()) changes "this" to be the first argument
myfunc.call(document.getElementById("someid"));
```

Jquery uses `this` to refer to the current element being processed. In events that would be the target element. In `.each` it is the current element in the collection.

Consider:

```
$(".promotion").click(function() { 
   alert(this); // will alert with the div that was clicked
});
```

In Jquery you can wrap any html element with a [JQuery Object](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#jQuery) by using `$(element)`. So when `this` is an html element like in the example above you can use `$(this)`:

```
$(".promotion").click(function() { 
   alert($(this).attr("id")); // will alert with the div that was clicked
});
```

Play around with it here: http://jsbin.com/okuri3/edit.

More about `this`:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html
- http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/

Comment: But you can always use $(this) to get it as a jQuery object of course. +1

Comment: Please check my updates as it might clarify bit further of what actually I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Hober: yup, if you need to. @Rachel: Can you post some more of your code? I don't understand what exactly you're trying to do from your update. If you already have a function that is called for every element, why can't you just call `element.id` or `$(element).attr("id")` to get the id of the specific element that was passed to the function?

Comment: @Joel Potter: Updated my question with some code, hope it makes little more sense in here now.

Comment: Basically I want to understand the use of `this` in jquery and make use of it in my question to make sure that attribute value am getting is always for the current container.

Comment: @Joel Potter: I understand this explanation but what I am trying to see is that if I have multiple containers on the page and I have init function which is being called for each of the container and inside the init function am using `var id = $( '.promotion' ).attr( 'id' );` than how can I make sure that I am getting attribute value for the current container only and not other similar container, something like this.container.attr('id') but currently this gives an error...am not sure why...Am I making some sense here ?

Comment: @Rachel. Please show some more markup. Particularly the init function, and how it is called.